# Failed to install Tk module of Perl in Windows7

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

At first,I tried to use ppm and cpanm to install Tk module.But failed to download whth the reason which i don't konw(yet i can install image module) .So I tried another way.I downloaded the Tk-804.030 from the cpan website.And unpacked it.Then I type "perl makefile.pl" in the cmd, howerver, shit happens.There were so many errors.And i remenbered to read the README.txt, so i found the following which make me frustrated.

*When you install ActivePerl, it provides patched C runtime as **PerlCRT.dll**
 which it installs in the "system32" directory.
This needs "administrator" rights on NT.
It also provides the import library **PerlCRT.lib**, but this is installed
 in an odd location e.g. C:\ActivePerl\lib\CORE\PerlCRT.lib 
where it is not found by MakeMaker or VC++.I copied it to C:\VisualStudio\VC98\lib\PerlCRT.lib
(Your paths may vary dependinh where you installed ActivePerl and VC++.)*

I could not find the PerlCRT.dll and PerlCRT.lib in my computer, i googled and found PerlCRT.dll which could be downloaded, but i counld find PerlCRT.lib to download.i don't kown how to do it, i really need some help.It couldn't be better if you can tell me the whole installing procedure. ( I'm new to Perl, and I use Win7, visual studio 2012 and MinGW as well)

Comment: If you have ActivePerl than you already have Tkx installed. Why you need Tk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [PPM Tk info page](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Tk/), the distro fails to build on the current versions of ActiveState Perl for Windows. You can add the [3rd party Bribes repository, Tk is available there](http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppmdir.html#Tk).

Comment: Thank you.I have solved it.Now I added the Bribes repo and i found why i was wrong when i compiled the Tk module was that I use the latest Tk-804.030,however,activestate Perl just support the Tk-804.029,damn Windows